# how to call next page from ArrayAdapter class in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Hai Friends i am newbie for Android ..how to navigate from ArrayAdapter Class to Another activity class.i don't know how to navigate.I know "intent" keyword is used to navigate one activity to another activity..but now i am using ArrayAdapter Class,if i use "intent" keyword  to navigate another activity i get error.

```
package org.ajsquare.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
 import android.database.DataSetObserver;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.sax.StartElementListener;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Teamname extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{



  private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private String[] mStrings;
private TypedArray mimages;
String mteam=null;
private int mViewResourceId;
Context c;

public Teamname(Context context, int textViewResourceId,TypedArray images,String[] test) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId,test);
    c=context;
    mimages=images;
    mViewResourceId=textViewResourceId;
    mInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mStrings=test;
        }

public int getCount()
{

    return mStrings.length;
}

public String getId(int position)
{
    return mStrings[position];

}

public long getItemId(int position)
{

    return 0;

}


public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
{

            convertview=mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);



    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.image_teamname);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(mimages.getDrawable(position));
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        System.out.println(position);

        //Intent intent=new Intent(Teamname.this,Team_details.class);// i am getting error from this line
                    //startActivity(this);

        }
    });

    return convertview;

}




     }
```

// i cann't use intent in this Class.. pls give solution

Answer (score 5):

if Your class is `NonActivityClass` so use `context` to start new Activity....

```
Intent intent=new Intent(c,Team_details.class);
c.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Teamname.this,Team_details.class); 
startActivity(this);
```

use this code and try::::

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Teamname.this,Team_details.class);
startActivity(intent);
```